# http outbound gateway httpstatuscodeexception

Tags: rest, http, spring-integration

If the http outbound gateway throws a httpstatuscodeexception ... will it bubble up to the place where i invoke the gateway method.  I cant seem to catch the exception there

I have the below config

```
<int:channel id="responseChannel" />

<int:gateway id="someGateway"  service-interface="someinterface"       default-request-channel="requestChannel"      default-reply-channel="responseChannel"        default-reply-timeout="${reply.timeout}"> 
<int:method name ="somemethod">

</int:gateway> 

<int:chain id="some-gateway-chain" input-channel="requestChannel" output-    channel="responseChannel">  
<int:object-to-json-transformer />
<int-http:outbound-gateway       url-expression="some url"         http-method="POST"         expected-response-type-expression="some.RESPONSE_TYPE"     request-factory="somehttpClientFactory" reply-timeout="${reply.timeout}"/>
</int:chain>
```

EDIT : -------------------------------------------------------

can i do the below

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" output-channel="some other channel"> 

<int-groovy:script> how do i check if the payload.message.cause is a httpstatuscodeexception and then throw it from here 
</int-groovy:script> </int:service-activator>
```

Comment: Another question I have is if  the gateway and the http gateway are configured with an error-handler. is there a way to still let the httpstatuscodeexception or restclientexception bubble up

Answer (score 1):

Add an `error-channel` to the `<int:gateway/>` and handle the exception there. The message on the error channel is an `ErrorMessage` with the payload a `MessagingException` with properties `failedMessage` and `cause`.

The error flow can either throw another exception or return some other result.

In response to your **EDIT**:

err...

```
if (payload.cause instanceof ...) {
    throw payload.cause
}
someOtherResult
```

Comment: 1)is there any workaround to have  gateway be connected to two error channels

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - it's unreadable - edit your question. I am not sure what you mean by "two error channels".

Comment: Edited the question.  I have an global errorchanel that we already have configured which will take the error and transform it and put it on a quueue. I was wondering if i can take the same Errormessage and send it to another errorchannel

Comment: Messages only go to `errorChannel` if it is declared as the `error-channel` on the gateway or there's a poller somewhere in the flow. I generally recommend using a custom `error-channel` when providing custom error handling.